# I want a Notice message when save configuration

Tags: forms

I have a module and a form with a checkbox...What i really want is when the user press the button save configuration to take a notice message..Could anyone know how to do this thing?

```
foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $severity) {
    $severity_options[$severity] = check_plain(drupal_ucfirst($severity));
  }

  // Generate checkbox list for given severity levels.
  $form['severity'] = array(
    '#type'        => 'fieldset',
    '#title'       => t('Select the severity.'),
    '#collapsible' => true,
    '#collapsed'   => true,
  );

  $form['severity']['severity_levels'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
    '#options'       => $severity_options,
    '#default_value' => array_values($severity_levels),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We cannot explain you the form API at this level because we would duplicate the documentation. If you have a more specific question, we can help, but "How can I show a message when the user click the button" is too broad.

Comment: We cannot even explain you how to write a module, since that is one of those things you are supposed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned is correct bit more Explanation on that

Syntax : `drupal_set_message($message = NULL, $type = 'status', $repeat = TRUE);`

**Example usage:**

```
drupal_set_message(t('your message to the user.'), 'error');
```

**Parameters**

**string $message:** (optional) The translated message to be displayed to the user. For consistency with other messages, it should begin with a capital letter and end with a period.

**string $type:** (optional) The message's type. Defaults to 'status'. These values are supported:

```
**'status'
'warning'
'error'**
```

**bool $repeat:** (optional) If this is FALSE and the message is already set, then the message won't be repeated. Defaults to TRUE.
Return value

array|null A multidimensional array with keys corresponding to the set message types. The indexed array values of each contain the set messages for that type. Or, if there are no messages set, the function returns NULL.

Comment: ok that answer i read about that but where i will write it down??in order when checkbox will not have checked items this will gets out the notice?

Comment: Add a form alter and in submit add a submit callback and put the code there the message will be displayed after submit callback is called

Comment: i am new in drupal i will edit my code and help me a little more plz?

Comment: Sure go ahead i ll help you out

Comment: i wrote my code plz help me

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7 check this link how they used drupal set message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23255/discussion-between-devaraj-johnson-and-karmen).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `drupal_set_message()` (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) from your form submit function:

```
  function YOURFORM_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // Perform your tasks...
    drupal_set_message(t('Button pressed'), 'status');
  }
```

Your message will be displayed on the default location of the page (depending on the theme) after submitting the form. You can specify different message types, such as 'status', 'warning' or 'error'.

Hope that helps,

Comment: ok that answer i read about that but where i will write it down??in order when checkbox will not have checked items this will gets out the notice?

Comment: @Karmen I just edited my answer. The message will be displayed somewhere on the page, depending on the theme. If your form does not redirect to any other page, it will probably appear on the top of the refreshed form, if you are using the standard admin theme.

Comment: on the .admin.inc file??

Comment: Rather on the template. According to the drupal_set_message() documentation, "Messages are stored in a session variable and displayed in page.tpl.php via the $messages theme variable."